# how to replace space of a string with "," and convert into array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yii2

I have a text box.
I am enter the value in text box like 12 13 14.
and i am want to convert this into 12,13,14 and then convert it into array and show each separate value.

Comment: Invalid HTML structure `tr/td` can't be direct child of `form`.

Comment: So nothing to do with anything other than HTML (and perhaps JavaScript)?

Comment: [Have a read](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775/HTML-For-Beginners)

Comment: PHP code
<?php
 $da=$_POST['imp'];
 $ar = implode(',',$da);
  foreach($ar as $k) die("not in the loop");
  {
  $q="insert into pb_100_fp (draw_3_fp) values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $k)."')"; 
  $rs=mysqli_query($conn, $q);
  echo "$k";
}
exit;
?>

Answer (score 2):

If your form field asks for the values without a comma, then you will need to `explode` the POST data by space. What you're doing now is imploding it by comma (you can't implode a string to begin with), and then trying to pass that into a foreach loop. However, a foreach loop will only accept an array.

```
$ar = explode(' ',$da);
```

That simple change should fix it for you. You will want to get rid of the peculiar `die()` after your foreach (invalid syntax, and unclear what you're trying to do there!), and validate your data before the loop instead. By default, if you explode a string and no matching delimiters are found, the result will be an array with a single key, which you can pass into a loop without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to expect the user enters data in that particular format? I mean, what if the user uses more than one space character, or separate the numbers actually with commas? or with semicolons? or enters letters instead of numbers? Anyway.. at least you could transform all the spaces to a single space character and then do the explode() as suggested:

```
$da = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['imp'])); 
$ar = explode(' ', $da);
```

before your foreach().

Answer (score -1):

use explode instead of implode as

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.

and you cannot do foreach operation for a string.

```
    $da=$_POST['imp']; 
    $ar = explode(' ',$da);
    foreach($ar as $k)
    {
        $q="insert into pb_100_fp (draw_3_fp) values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $k)."')"; 
        $rs=mysqli_query($conn, $q); 
        echo $k.","; 
    }
```

then you will get this output

```
o/p : 12,13,14,
```